# Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, war

Caused by:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE")
}
}
group 'batch'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

bootRun {
addResources = true
}

war {
baseName = 'Batch'
version =  '0.1.0'
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.Application'
}
}
jar {
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': 'src.main.java.com.Application'
}
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.7
targetCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.24'
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'
compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.tomcat.embed', name: 'tomcat-embed-jasper', version: '7.0.82'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.2.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.7.4.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.1.1'
}
```

Technologies used:

Gradle, Springboot,jdk7

Exception Trace:

> tionConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh att
>   empt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/aut
>   oconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persist
>   ence unit root URL
>   2018-05-14 21:11:04.427  INFO 3136 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2018-05-14 21:11:04.505  INFO 3136 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)

2018-05-14 21:11:04.552 ERROR 3136 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfi
gure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence u
nit root URL
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEAS
E.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.j
ar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar
!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.R
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1076) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:851) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.ja
r!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEA
SE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.4.0.RELEASE]
        at com.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [Batch-0.1.0.war:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [Batch-0.1.0.war:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [Batch-0.1.0.war:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59) [Batch-0.1.0.war:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:603) ~[spring-orm
-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:443) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELE
ASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:424) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/
:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[spring-orm-4.3
.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.ja
r!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.REL
EASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.REL
EASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEAS
E.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187) ~[spring-core-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:600) ~[spring-orm
-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.2.RELEASE]
        ... 31 common frames omitted

Comment: paste full statcktrace to you question

Comment: @SAM added full stacktrace to the question.

Comment: Your error is because of hibernate entitymanger factory. Post your DAO, Entity , Service and Controller codes. Error is due to session factory hibernate.

Comment: Post your codes, i will see them after 12 hours.

Comment: @SAM solved. Removed compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.1.1'.  Added Entity
public class TestEntity {
    Id
    GeneratedValue
    private int id;
}

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Removed

```
compile group: 'org.eclipse.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence', version: '2.1.1'
```

Added a class like below

```
@Entity
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
}
```